# Parallel Space game progress file location

Tags: data-recovery, google-play-games, virtualbox

I've been using parallel space on my Android device for a while now but it's been having an issue with logging in to the Google Play services and thus backing up my game progress becomes hectic. I'd like to know where the progress files are stored in my file manager so that I can cut and paste it manually. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't have rooted phone, you can not do it. Problem is in PS, in most cases you need to change settings of PS. So tap on three dots in right upper corner, go to Speed Mode and turn it off.
Speed Mode can reduce battery consumption and speed the PS, but it also disaable Google Play services to achive that.